# How To Tell Django Ive Overridden A Third Party App

Tags: django, django-apps, django-notification, django-packages

Im wanting to add functionality to a [Django-Notifications](https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications) view. I guess the best way to do this is to override the class, add my custom logic, then pass the class to super:

```
from notifications import AllNotificationsList

class CustomAllNotificationsList(AllNotificationsList):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # my custom logic
        return super(CustomAllNotificationsList, self).get_queryset(self)
```

I know of [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-the-default-admin-site) guide for overriding Django Admin, but I cant find how to do this for other third party packages.

My questions are:

1. I dont know where to put this overridden class (in my project tree).
2. I dont know how to tell Django that it has been overridden (settings.py?).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I ended up doing this:

[https://medium.com/@*RStein*/extending-third-party-django-app-without-touching-its-code-d35fb136c08f](https://medium.com/@_RStein_/extending-third-party-django-app-without-touching-its-code-d35fb136c08f)

It's a bit hacky but its the best I could find.